# How to correctly deliver errors from a RESTful API?

Tags: java, json, api, rest, error-reporting

I am referring to [this project on Github](https://github.com/jefferythewind/movie_rental).  So this is supposed to be a RESTful API for managing a movie rental service.  I mean it technically "works" right now, but one of the things it will do is deliver the error messages directly to the client from the internal methods.

Take this code for example:

```
/*
GET films
*/
get("/films", (req, res) -> {
    try {
        String json_output = get_film_list();
        return json_output;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "{\"error\":\"There was an error: " + e.toString().replace("\"","") + "\"}";
    }
});
```

And we have the `get_film_list()` method:

```
public static String get_film_list()  throws SQLException, URISyntaxException{
    Connection connection = ConnectionPool.getDBCP2Connection();
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM films");

    String output = "{\"films\":[";
    int got_result = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        output += "{\"id\":\""+rs.getInt(1)+"\",\"name\":\""+rs.getString(2)+"\",\"type\":\""+rs.getInt(3)+"\"},";
        got_result = 1;
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    output = output.substring(0, output.length()-1) + "]}";

    if (got_result == 1){
        return output;
    }else{
        throw new SQLException("No films.");
    }
}
```

So the errors are delivered to the user via the API.  I found this pretty convenient for development.  I knew that if the server response contains the `error` property then there was an error, and it supplies the error message.  I have heard through code review that this is not the way to do this at all.  I also suspect that perhaps you're supposed to give formal HTTP errors or something.  But at the same time I figured I would want my api to always return nice JSON formatted strings.

When a user hasn't authenticated, they will see this:

> {"error":"Please Authenticate."}

I created an error in the DB connection class, and the user would see this:

> {"error":"There was an error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC
>   driver class 'org.postgresql.Drive'"}

So, my question comes down to, what is the proper way to return error messages to the users with a RESTful API.  One of this sort which uses returns JSON data.

Thanks!

Comment: Rest protocol is based on http (it is not the case for Soap) so I think you have to use http error using http headers. But you can always put a pretty error json in the body. So you can do both ;)

Comment: "There was an error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Drive" - That's exactly what makes a user go "WTF??" The user is not interested if there was an SQLException. He wants to be told "Please authenticate!" or "The was an internal Server error. Please contact costumer service."

Comment: Side note on code quality: please study java coding guidelines. You don't use "_" within method names. Never. Ever.

Comment: Returning an appropriate status code can be more useful than a String message in JSON. For instance, most developers will know what 404 means, whereas "Not Found" as a string message won't be as apparent.

Answer (score 3):

RESTful services are based on 2 things, the response code and the actual response itself.

Well, basically it boils down to what error you want to handle. This particular scenario means no data being found and you would find different ways of handling this scenario. Any other error conditions would be handled differently

The 2 approaches to handling this error are

### Scenario 1:

Response Code: 200 OK
 Response: {}

which means that there was no data for the request specified(more so the parameters supplied with the request)

### Scenario 2:

Response Code: 404 Not Found
 Response: {"error":"Error Message"}

but this could potentially be confusing to indicate that the service was not found. But this depends on how you've defined your RESTful API.

From what I understand, the above scenario is a mix of both, where it sends out a 200 OK, but at the same time an error message too which is not the way to do it.

Its best to read through the rules of REST and then come up with your API.

Also it might be worth documenting your API through SWAGGER or RAML which makes it meaningful to someone using the service without going through tons of code to understand it.

Comment: I've been working a little with the Instagram API, there is a brief description here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ They always feed a `meta` property which contains a `code`.  That code looks like it is always an HTTP status code.  If it is not 200 then they provide error message as well.  Do you think this would be OK?  All the code and error msg is inside the json formatted string?  Not sure if you are implying that it is possible to send an http response code beside the json output?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: Am guessing you've got your answers by now. Sorry I wasn't around yesterday

Comment: Well yes thank you, I realized I didn't quite understand as much as I need to about HTTP responses in general, and how sparkjava handles those.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using http you should use the [http status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) properly, for example the SQL exception would probably result in a response code of `500 Internal Server Error`, but you shouldn't expose the actual stack trace or exception at least for two reasons

1. The api-user has no use of that error message, he can't act upon it or take any reasonable actions to fix it.
2. You're exposing the applications internals, this could provide someone with malicious intent with valuable information.

When it comes to actually displaying an error. Hopefully something that the user can have some sort of use of. You can pretty much do it in any manner you feel fits your api. The important thing is that the api is consistent.

I'd say that the body of the response you're giving now is okay, except for the fact that the actual message probably doesn't mean anything to the intended user when you just call `toString()` on an `Exception`, that information is intended for the developers and should probably be logged.

What you need to do is, translate the exceptions to usable error messages and use http status codes.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a REST API on the top of the HTTP protocol, the HTTP status codes are the proper way to indicate the result of the operation. Along with the status code, you can return a message with more details about the error.

Find below the most common status codes of errors for situations when the client seems to have erred:

- [`400 Bad Request`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
- [`401 Unauthorized`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1)
- [`403 Forbidden`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)
- [`404 Not Found`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
- [`409 Conflict`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
- [`422 Unprocessable Entity`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)

Don't define your own status codes. Stick to the standards.

---

When returning a message, your HTTP response can be like:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json

{ "error" : "Resource not found with the requested identifier" }
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to feed the codes back inside a json formatted variable?  Like for example in the instagram API they always provide a `meta` property which contains a `code` property (http status code).  https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind The Instagram API responses are contained by an envelope with the HTTP status code. That's just fine if you return the proper HTTP status code in the response too.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind If the client requested a resource that could not be found, return a `404 Not Found` error in the HTTP response. Along with it, you can return a JSON that contains the `404` HTTP status code too. But keep it consistent: do not return `200 OK` as the HTTP status code and `404` in your JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out.  I think I understand after dwelling on it for a little while.  I think I need to read more about how sparkjava is delivering the http responses.  I think what you're getting at is that in my GET method, it is returning a string, in this case JSON formatted, but by simply returning a string, it is giving a 200 HTTP response, but the msg is error.  If the user isn't authenticated, I issue a `halt(401, "{\"error\":\"Please Authenticate.\"}");`.  This way is probably more accurate, since I give an error code, then my custom message.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind My advice is: stick to the standards and return the most appropriate HTTP code for each situation. For example, don't return a `200 OK` when you are requesting a resource that doesn't  exist; a `404 Not Found ` is much better. Don't return a `200 OK` if the authenticated user has no permission to access a resource; a `403 Forbidden` is the right response for this situation. Along with the `4xx` status codes, you can return a descriptive message or the error. It will help the client to understand what was wrong with the request.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Let me know if you need any further clarification :)

Comment: Thanks!  I read through the sparkjava documentation, and in side every server call function they make available the request and response objects.  I think the response object is what I have been missing.  For example, `response.status(403)`, `response.body(json_string)`